# Control Left Arrow doesn't work - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, sleep

I am having a problem with my HP Pavilion computer.

Every time I type something, and start to use the shortcut Ctrl+Left Arrow key, it doesn't respond. The keyboard works perfectly fine overall, including other shortcuts but not this one.

My laptop is an HP Pavilion x360 computer with Windows 10. It works after a while, but then when it goes to sleep or about to go to sleep mode, or at a small period of time--to which I don't know how long--it stops working. Sometimes it does not work without sleep mode.

I have tried to contact HP support for it, but they suck. I keep being sent to tech-supports from outside the state who can't speak good English and cannot understand what my problem is. Some has to cut me off mid-sentence, including when I have not finished explaining the situation or asking me the same repeated question over and over. Plus they are very rude.

I've also gone through the forums with similar stories, but I can't find one with an legitimate answer. Just sympathy for the one having the same problem too.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume you don't have any keyboard mapping tools?

I suggest you try AutoHotKey and map that combination to something else, like opening Task Manager. This will then prove if the issue is the combination of the 2 keys being pressed/sent, or the program where you're using this not accepting it always (for unknown reasons).

Test this new combination with no programs open from the desktop to make sure it works every time.

If it does work each time, open the program where this issue occurs again verify if this combination works every time (if it opens Task Scheduler).

If it does, map CTRL + Left Arrow to itself (eg, map CTRL + LEFT ARROW to CTRL + LEFT ARROW) to see if that has any affect.